# Is there any way to improve performance while inserting rows into Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, vba, adodb

I need to insert more than thousand rows into an Oracle Database table every 6 hours using VBA module. During every run some complex forecasting calculation is done in VBA and the resulting values have to be inserted into the database.

The typical output Range consists of more than 1000 rows and 13 columns.

Currently I insert row by row and moreover an auto-commit runs after each insert(ADO DB *default*). Is there a better method or process for improving performance here?

It currently takes around 20 - 40 minutes depending on the server load. Any performance improvements Suggestions.

Comment: I wonder how much of that time is in Oracle and how much time is in VBA.  An extended SQL trace with '`DBMS_MONITOR.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE` might help you determine where the time is being spent.

Comment: That's very slow for 1000 rows. Have you tried parameterising the insert.  Just doing a single commit would also be faster.

Comment: ADO DB autocommits after every insert, I am looking into the comments made by Jens Schauder below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't do a commit after every insert (if this is compatible with your requirements)
2. Consider if using the append hint helps
3. Don't know VBA (anymore) but look for batch inserts, i.e. something that inserts multiple statements in one go instead of every insert statement on its own
4. Use prepare statements
5. Consider disabling constraints during insert

Comment: These are good points. I think that #1, #4 and #3 are the most important, and #2 and #5 are optimizations at a rather high level.

Comment: Thanks .. I'll try to research a bit more on the mentioned points

Answer (score 0):

May not be acceptable to you, but dropping any indexes on the table and then recreating once done would help.  (Saves the overhead of having to update the index on each INSERT)

Comment: I dont think this is a good option since there are other processes using the same table and creating and dropping indexes is also costly for only 1000 rows. If it would have been like a million this would have been they way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem my self. My problem was that i was opening and closing connections for each insert. This meant using 15 minutes to import about 1000 rows.

I solved this by keeping the connection open and sending new execute statements to the DB with a loop before closing the connection again.

This is my VBA:

```
' Setup the connection to the DB
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
strConnection = "Provider=OraOLEDB.oracle;Data Source=connectionstring;User Id=username;Password=yourpasswrod;"

' Open DB connection
conn.ConnectionString = strConnection
conn.Open

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    conn.Execute ("insert into my_table ( user, user_info) values ('1', '" & ActiveCell.value &"')")
Loop

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

This redused the time to inport down to about 30 seconds. :)